# Identify a special character in an array of chars

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a client/server application. I have a Message class with several String fields. I have written the following method to return a char[] of these fields:

```
public char[] toArrayOfChar()
{
    String str = "";
    char[] charr;
    str += from;
    str += "\r\n";
    str += to;
    str += "\r\n";
    str += header;
    str += "\r\n";
    str += body;
    str += "\r\n";
    str += header;
    str += "\r\n";
    charr = str.toCharArray();

    return charr;
}
```

Now I want to separate each field and convert it to a String after I have sent it from client to server.  How do I identify the carriage return and line feed characters at the end of each field?

Comment: StringTokenizer can help.  But maybe there is a better way.

Comment: ++StringTokenizer, or if you feel the masta regEx also works. Although I'd just use \n and split as simplest as it gets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your actual question, good answers have been given, but about your code style:

It's horribly inefficient to use multiple String += calls. Here's a much more efficient version.

First define a constant for cr + lf:

```
private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
```

Now use `StringBuilder` to build the `String`, like this:

```
public char[] toArrayOfChar()
{
    return new StringBuilder()
        .append(from).append(CRLF)
        .append(to).append(CRLF)
        .append(header).append(CRLF)
        .append(body).append(CRLF)
        .append(header).append(CRLF)
        .toString()
        .toCharArray();
}
```

This is both easier to read and more efficient (your version has to create a new String instance for every += call).

Also, maybe you should just write this code (minus the `.toCharArray()` line) in your object's `toString()` method and do `this.toString().toCharArray()` to get the `char[]`. It's always a good practice to utilize standard mechanisms, this is what the `toString()` method is for, [create a String representation of the object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into the `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader` classes, as suggested in the [official trail: Reading from and Writing to Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).

Using these classes you can simply send your strings using

```
out.println(from);
out.println(to);
out.println(header);
out.println(body);
```

and read using

```
String from   = bufferedReader.readLine();
String to     = bufferedReader.readLine();
String header = bufferedReader.readLine();
String body   = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Comment: I see your method is much easier, but I have to do this method as I mentioned above. any way thanks :)